# How can I use Google Apps Script's UrlFetchApp to login to a third party website that has a drop-down select box in the login process

Tags: google-apps-script

I trying to use google apps script to login this website: [tvg.com](http://tvg.com)

The code comes from another Stack Overflow answer and seems to work fine (I've tested on other sites successfully) except for the drop-down box to select the State. I'm not sure if the issue is that the State selections are created dynamically by javascript or if the actual field that I'm entering is hidden.  My code is below:

```
function Tvg() {
var payload =
   {
     "accountField" : "00000",             //not the actual account number
     "pinField" : "0000",                  // not the actual password
     "stateField" : "Massachusetts", 
   };
  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false
   };
  var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.tvg.com/" , options);
  var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
  Logger.log(sessionDetails);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to make this work.

Comment: try with the url of https://www.tvg.com/login

Comment: @teatimer - thanks for the suggestion, but it still didn't work.  I don't think I'm populating that state field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state field name is "stateAbbr" and should be the two-letter abbreviation of the state name. You may also need to include a field called "loginType".

I skimmed these details by examining the POST request sent by the Login form on their page.  Since I don't have a valid account I couldn't test the final outcome.

```
function Tvg() {
  var payload =
      { "loginType":"tvgup",
        "accountField" : "00000",             //not the actual account number
        "pinField" : "0000",                  // not the actual password
        "stateAbbr" : "AK", 
      };
  var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "payload" : payload,
        "followRedirects" : false
      };
  var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.tvg.com/login" , options);
  var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
  Logger.log(sessionDetails);
}
```

Note that it's possible the site is checking other factors, such as the referrer url or a Cookie to validate login requests.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I will give this a try.  I'm a bit surprised by the abbreviation, because when I login myself I can either type or select the state name typed out.   Thanks again.

Comment: This worked. Thanks.  Where did you come up withe the "loginType" : "tvgup" line.  Also, now that I'm logged in, can you refer me to any references that will help me extract data, click on links.   Thanks again.

Comment: I figured out the parameters using the Network panel in the Chrome developer tools, which allows you to view the requests sent/received by the browser.    https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-resource-details

I haven't used Apps Script to crawl a site before, so I'm not sure what the best approach is.   This might help you get started, https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html